# Spring - How 'multiple' AOP behaviors to services are resolved?

Tags: java, spring, proxy, aop, java-ee-6

I want to know that whether we can apply 'multiple' `AOP` behaviors to our service classes or not?

Lets just say, i do this to my `BankServiceImpl` class:

- `@Transactional` on top of one of the method, `accountTransfer()`, and
- and some custom `<aop>` pointcut on the execution of another method `someOtherMethod()`.

Then will Spring be able to generate **one** proxy where `accountTransfer()` is made transactional and `someOtherMethod()` is also given `aop` behaviour?

Does any one has an idea on how Spring resolves multiple `AOP` behaviors?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It looks like Spring creates a single proxy object with all of the advice types in it.  This proxy object will implement the `org.springframework.aop.framework.Advised` regardless of if it's a JDK dynamic proxy or a CGLIB proxy.

If you have multiple advisors, the order of their execution is undefined unless you make it explict by implementing the `Ordered` interface or the `@Ordered` annotation.  You can find more on ordering [here](http://static.springsource.org/spring/docs/2.5.x/reference/aop.html#aop-ataspectj-advice-ordering).  Springs transactional aspects default to lowest priority.